# How to recover a dropped database on MySQL

Tags: database-administration, recovery, system-administration

I accidentaly dropped a database on MySQL yog ultimate. Also, I found that the IT guy uninstalled MySQL yog from the machine.

Now am working on two machines which includes the one from which database was dropped and mysql was uninstalled.

Is there a way to recover the dropped databases.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. It's either a DBA or system administration question.

Comment: if mysql binary log is enabled, there is a chance you can regenerate data

Answer (score 2):

There's really only one word: **Backups**.

Comment: Anyother option besides backups. I had a word with a friend of mine and he says that there is connection specific recycle bin from where the same can be recovered.However, i've no information on that. Please assist.

Comment: The only reliable method is backups. When you drop a database it doesn't end up in the recycle bin, it's deleted immediately. If another process generates data it will likely overwrite those files and trash whatever hopes you have at recovery. You could always try data recovery tools, but databases typically consist of many files each of which have to be in a very specific state or the thing is too corrupted to load.

Comment: I hate to sound so severe, but if this data was important to you, there would've been backups. Hard drives fail. People make mistakes. Data that isn't backed up is data that will eventually go away without a trace. You should do an audit of everything important to your work and make absolutely sure you have a backup and recovery strategy for it.

Comment: Dear @tadman back ups were there but they were done couple of hours before the damage happened. I appreciate your help and concern, However if possible am looking forward for a solution that can actually bring all the things back. This includes the data too which wasnt backed up.

Comment: Best plan is to restore from backups. The rest of the data should be considered lost. If you have binary logs you *may* be able to extract from that the operations that were performed since the last backup was made, but this could take a very long amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

You said in a comment that you have a backup from a couple of hours prior to the data loss.

If you also have binary logs, you can restore the backup, and then reapply changes from the binary logs.

Here is documentation on this operation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/point-in-time-recovery.html

You can even filter the binary logs to reapply changes for just one database (mysqlbinlog --database *name*). For example you may have other databases that were not dropped on the same instance, and you wouldn't want to reapply changes to those other databases.

Recovering two hours worth of binary logs won't take "a very long amount of time." The trickiest part is figuring out the start point to begin replaying the binary logs. If you were lucky enough to include the binary log position with the backup, this will be simpler and very precise. If you have to go by timestamp, it's less precise and you probably cannot hope to do an exact recovery.

If you didn't have binary logs enabled on this instance since you backed up the database, it's a lot trickier to do a data recovery of lost files. You might be able to use a filesystem undelete tool like the [EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard](http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery/data-recovery-software/free-mysql-database-recovery.htm) (though I can't say I have experience using that tool).

Reconstructing the files you recover is not for the faint of heart, and it's too much to get into here. You might want to get help from a professional MySQL consulting firm. I work for one such firm, Percona, who offers [data recovery services](http://www.percona.com/products/mysql-consulting/data-recovery).

Comment: Thank You Bill. I know at what time the database was dropped. I hope this can be of some help in order to set the start point.

Comment: No, the start point is the time your backup was made. You want to replay the binary log starting from that time, to just *before* the time the database was dropped.

Comment: How much will your firm charge me in bringing the databases back to picture.

Comment: See consulting rates for pay-as-you-go work here: http://www.percona.com/products/mysql-consulting/prices

Comment: To the person who tried to edit my answer: my apologies for plugging my employer. I know StackExchange is a place for answers, not to plug businesses. I offered a reasonable amount of free, usable advice before I mentioned the data recovery service. StackExchange has a [content policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy) and I don't believe I violated it.

Answer (score 0):

After MySQL drops database the data is still on the media for a while. So you can fetch records and rebuild database with DBRECOVER.

mysql> drop database employees;
Query OK, 14 rows affected (0.16 sec)

#sync
#sync

select drop database recovery

select MYSQL VERSION as you used; Page Size should be left as 16k

click select directory , and input the @@datadir directory

!!!caution: you should input the @@datadir directory here. pls don't copy the @@datadir directory to any other filesystem or mount point , and use the copy one . The software need to scan the orginal filesystem or mount point ,otherwise it can't work.You'd better set @datadir mount point as read only, avoid any more disk write is necessary. And don't locate DBRECOVER software package on the same filesystem.

https://youtu.be/ao7OY8IbZQE