# Recover Mysql Database after drop database command

Tags: mysql

I accidentally deleted my data in the production database using `drop database ...` command. I am using InnoDB but I don't enable `mysqlbinlog`. How to recover the data?

Comment: Or perhaps more https://stackoverflow.com/q/25671165/3001761 if you don't have the logs.

Comment: please don't do this I need an urgent answer. I do not enable `mysqlbinlog` so the question does not answer me.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/3001761; if you need urgent help, you should *hire some*.

Comment: You should at least have a backup so you may only loose 24hrs of data?

Comment: I only have `ib_logfile0` `ib_logfile1` `ibdata1` and `ibtmp1`